# inserting multiple ordinality attributes/values to datomic db

Tags: clojure, insert, datomic

So far my add-post-to-datomic method looks like

```
(defn add-post-to-datomic [title, content, useremail]
  (d/transact conn [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user),
                     :post/title title,
                     :post/content content,
                     :author/email useremail}]))
```

I would really like to add functionality to add a potentially variable number of tags.

In my awesome-schema.edn I have

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident :post/tag
 :db/valueType :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
 :db/doc "tag applied to a post"
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

So it's okay if there are multiple ones in the db thanks to the cardinality set to many.

How can I write the above method to also work for a variable number of tags ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Transactions Docs](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html) under "Cardinality many transactions". As long as you pass a set of tags this should work:

```clj
(defn add-post-to-datomic [title content user-email tag-set]
  (d/transact conn [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
                     :post/title title
                     :post/content content
                     :post/tag tag-set
                     :author/email user-email}]))
```

Comment: lisp is so deceptively simple sometimes... :D

Comment: It seems that this is still an append though, not a put/replace?